# Wait for JS Callback After evaluateJavaScript

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to wait for javascript callback, however, the swift callback is being called before the javascript callback. How can I wait for JS callback?

```
AppWebView.evaluateJavaScript("$('.loading-gif').removeClass('hide', function() { return true } );") { (Any, Error) in
\\ .loading-gif successfully hided.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this using `evaluateJavaScript`, since it's callback is called as soon as the evaluated Javascript returns. This is most likely before your asynchronous call is done.

You will need to register a message handler in your swift code similar to…

```
let script = WKUserScript(source: javascriptString, 
                          injectionTime: injectionTime, 
                          forMainFrameOnly: true)
userContentController.addUserScript(script)
webView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, 
                                            name: "didShowLoading")
```

You can then define a delegate method in your Swift code…

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController,
    didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {

    if message.name == "didShowLoading" {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Finally, you can post the message from your javascript code…

```
var script = "$('.loading-gif').removeClass('hide', function() {"
           + "  webkit.messageHandlers['didShowLoading'].postMessage('');"
           + "});"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script)
```

Comment: What is the difference between `javascriptString` and `script` (in the bottom snippet)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

On JS side:

```
bridge.registerHandler("show_loading", function(data, responseCallback) {
    $('.loading-gif').removeClass('hide', function() { 
     responseCallback(true) 
    } );
})
```

And on Swift side:

```
self.bridge.callHandler("show_loading",data:nil, handler: { (data:AnyObject!) in
            //do whatever you want...
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could notify the native iOS code via a callback from the javascript callback. If you add something like this to your javascript:

`window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(JSON.stringify( { callback: 'show_loading' }  ));`

Then on the native side setup a WKUserContentController for your WKWebView (installed on the WKWebViewConfiguration). Your userContentController.didReceiveScriptMessage handler will get called with the JSON sent from the Javascript side.